# How to wrap the login function using RxJava

Tags: rx-java2

Below is the code which I am using.

```
public interface LoginCallback {

    void onSuccess();

    void onFailed();
}

//asynchronous function
public void login(LoginCallback callback) {
    …
}
```

How to wrap the login function using rxJava,like this-

```
public Single<Boolean> login() {
    //login(new LoginCallback...)
    return Single.xxxxx;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like
`Single.fromCallable(()-> login(new LoginCallback...));`

You can also use some type of result in your login function

```
Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(SingleEmitter<Boolean> e) throws Exception {
                LoginResult loginResult = login();
                if(loginResult.success())
                    e.onSuccess(true);
                else
                    e.onError(new LoginFailedException());
            }
        });
```